# shell_exec not running in websever

Tags: php, apache, raspberry-pi, shell-exec

I have an apache web sever with php file `/var/www/html/test.php`, and `servo.py` in the same directory.
When I go to `localhost/test.php` it doesn't work. Yet when I run `test.php` in an IDE it works fine. Any help?

test.php:

```
<?php
    shell_exec("python servo.py");
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a permissions error! I had to add www-data to the gpio group.

```
sudo adduser www-data gpio
```